# Unable to install MongooseIM from source code on MAC OS 10.14.2

Tags: macos, openssl, erlang, mongoose-im

I am unable to install Mongooseim (latest) from the source code.

Using:

```
MongooseIM 3.2.0 (source code)
Mac OS 10.14.2 
Erlang: 21.2
```

Issue: 
While compiling Mongooseim from the source code, my logs are stuck on linking fast_tls.so and execution stopped. See screenshot below. I am sure something is wrong with openssl.

Solution tried:

1. I have installed openssl and exported all flags but still the same issue.
2. I have tried to install fast_tls from the source code. But that also failed on openssl. see screenshot
3. Output of openssl verion

//terminal ouput

```
$ openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
built on: reproducible build, date unspecified
platform: darwin64-x86_64-cc
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx) 
compiler: clang -I. -I.. -I../include  -fPIC -fno-common -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -arch x86_64 -O3 -DL_ENDIAN -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/local/etc/openssl"
```

//Screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `which openssl`?

Comment: `$which openssl`
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl

Comment: Is it something related to keychain certificates, because I have deleted some certificates there which I feel not needed

Comment: Next you'll want to do `otool -L /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl`, then post the output; that command tells you where the library is located. Once that is done then you'll direct the compiler to that location perhaps using `--openssldir=` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: `/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl:
 /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.200.5)`

Comment: I have reinstall MAC OS for this issue. :(

Comment: After reinstall I am getting this below error: fatal error: 'openssl/err.h' file not found

Comment: Why would you need to reinstall `macOS`? That seems extreme. Try using the following command before running the `./configure` command: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2q/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188437/discussion-between-shubham1164-and-lll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this page regarding building ejabberd on MacOS should help:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/#installation

You need to install openSSL from homebrew and then properly set up your environment variables:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/expat/lib"
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include"
```